# How do I position these HTML elements with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to position the following elements such as on the image inside the "buttons-wrapper" div.

```
   <div id="buttons-wrapper">
            <div id="move-buttons-wrapper">
                <a href="#" class="main-btn move-btn" id="move-line-btn" onclick="setNewMove('line')">Ligne</a>
                <a href="#" class="main-btn move-btn" id="move-circle-btn" onclick="setNewMove('circle')">Cercle</a>
            </div>
            <div id="delay-wrapper">
                <input type="text" class="delay" id="delay-input" placeholder="Secondes à attendre" maxlength="6" size="10">
                <a href="#" class="main-btn delay" id="set-delay-btn" onclick="setDelay()">✚</a>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="main-btn" id="get-scene-btn" onclick="downloadSceneFile()">Télécharger la scène</a>
    </div>
```

[image: design]

I already made the style for the buttons and the input but I can't figure out how to position them properly.
I tried a few things but most of the time the elements are not affected by the CSS properties. Thaught a table display should do the trick but it failed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use flexbox if you want to align items in one direction either horizontally or vertically.

Wrap the `delay-wrapper` and `a.main-btn` into parent cotainer `bottom-wrapper` so that you can position one at left and other at other end using `justify-content: space-between;`

```css
#buttons-wrapper {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 2rem;    // Just to give some breathig space between childrens
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.main-btn {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: .25rem .5rem;
}

input.delay {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.bottom-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons-wrapper">
  <div id="move-buttons-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="main-btn move-btn" id="move-line-btn" onclick="setNewMove('line')">Ligne</a>
    <a href="#" class="main-btn move-btn" id="move-circle-btn" onclick="setNewMove('circle')">Cercle</a>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-wrapper">
    <div id="delay-wrapper">
      <input type="text" class="delay" id="delay-input" placeholder="Secondes à attendre" maxlength="6" size="10">
      <a href="#" class="main-btn delay" id="set-delay-btn" onclick="setDelay()">✚</a>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="main-btn" id="get-scene-btn" onclick="downloadSceneFile()">Télécharger la scène</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot !